# How to use zsh glob expansion to run same command multiple times?

Tags: shell, zsh, glob, expansion

I'm looking for the zsh syntax to run a single command multiple times with a range of parameters.

Instead of writing:

```sh
touch f_a
touch f_b
...
touch f_z
```

I'd like to execute:

```
touch f<a..z>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
touch f{a..z}
```

I think the name of the resource is **curly brace expansion**.

You can also use leading zeros:

```
echo file-{001..100}
```

On zsh you can print one item for each line like this:

```
printf '%s\n' {001..100}
```